# Mass Update Anything Download

Tags: appexchange

Where can I download Mass Update Anything utility? Link from AppExchange is not working.

Comment: Do you get an error ?

Comment: No, I can't find the download page. The download link on AppExchange [link](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/apex/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016YnREAU) takes me to developer force home page and the instruction on developer force takes me back to AppExchange but I cannot find the actual place where to download the installation exe.

Comment: I get it. same happens for MAC. Unfortunately there is no suppport for Salesforce lab products.

Comment: BTW - this appexchange Labs product has lots of limitations that may cause you to reject it after limited use